# Big black bug in Southern Germany

Tags: bugs, germany, bug-identification

Yesterday we were sitting on a porch and suddenly a wild bug appeared. It was completely black<sup>1</sup> and had no horn etc. It just looked like a common bug without any special features. Okay, nothing special so far, but it was huge! The insect was about 5 cm long. I've never seen such an animal before. Also, the guy was able to fly. After taking a nap on our table he flew away. The flight was a little bit turbulent. It hit every wall, lamp etc. it could find :)

Is one able to identify it without any picture and this vague information? This happened in South Germany (Central Europe) around 10:00 P.M..

---

**Footnotes:**

1. It was completely matt black. Not a single different color or a slightly shining green etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Female** [stag beetle?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stag_beetle)?

They don't have horns.

> Female stag beetles are usually smaller than the males, with smaller
>   mandibles.

and seem about the right size:

> Some species grow up to over 12 cm (4.7 in), but most are about 5 cm

There are [several species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxonomy_of_Lucanidae) and they vary in size too. Pretty much all beetles can, and do, fly.

---

Another option would be the **Blaps lethifera**:

[image: Blaps lethifera]

Comment: Thanks for your try, but it wasn't that one :( It was really black. Just completely matt black.

Comment: Updated @OddDeer

Comment: Seems right! :) Especially because we immediately shouted: "That's a stag beetle!" However, as we investigated the beetle, we saw that it doesn't have that "antler". We didn't have the a female version in mind :) Thanks!